# input arguments in shell scripting

Tags: shell, csh

This is my shell scripting that I'd used to run the vdb.txt and generate cov_urg_report:

```
#!/usr/bin/csh

urg -full64 -f ./vdb.txt -report ./cov_urg_report -format both -show tests
```

However, the script above can only be run in the same directory of the vdb.txt and the cov_urg_report will be generated in the same directory of the vdb.txt as well. I wanted to make in a way that the script can be run in different directory and user can specify the location of cov_urg_report to be generated at. I've tried using approach as shown below but it still end up generating the cov_urg_report in the same directory of vdb.txt.

```
#!/usr/bin/csh

urg -full64 -f $1/vdb.txt -report $2/cov_urg_report -format both -show tests
```

Comment: Why use `csh` for scripting?  Generally, it is better to use `sh` (or `bash`, or `ksh`, or perhaps `zsh`) for scripting.

Comment: Used properly, I think your script should work.  Your script doesn't check that `$1` and `$2` are provided.  It may be (though it is a bit unlikely) that the `urg` program does not respect the directory specified in the argument to the `-report` option.  You didn't show how you ran the command, but presumably it was something like `cov_urg_report /path/to/directory /tmp`.  Did you try `csh -x cov_urg_report /path/to/directory /tmp` to check that the shell did what you expected?

Comment: I would go farther than Jonathan and state the csh is completely unsuitable for scripting anything.  It has an ambiguous grammar, and should be avoided.  If you're comfortable with it as an interactive shell, by all means continue using it, but it is not a good tool for scripts.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I'll take note of that. I'm actually very new to scripting as I just started using it for about a week or two. This is actually a simple task that was given by my superior to work on and he specifically told me to use csh, thus, I have no choice but to use this for scripting. Thanks again for the suggestion. @WilliamPursell